# Can we add a Datacard inside canvas of type Fluid grid

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I am working on an app created by another resource, where the Canvas app contains a canvas of type fluid grid, as follow:-

[image: image.png]

so how we can add new DataCard inside the Fluid grid? or copy/paste existing datacards?

Answer (score 0):

On the screen you can see 'add section', this allows you to create a new datacard.
Hopefully this helps you!

Best regards